Conda deactivate switches back to previous environment
I noted that if I run
conda activate myenv1
conda activate myenv2
conda deactivate

then myenv1 is active. I would rather expect - after these three lines - no environment to be active at all.
So it seems that conda deactivate switches back to previously active environment (which I find a bit inconvenient).
Is this expected? If so where is it documented?

Maybe you could make a feature request for something like conda switch <env> that would do conda deactivate && conda activate <env>. Or conda deactivate --all flag to completely drop out. But anecdotally as a long term user, I can't think of situations where I fully use conda activate multiple times in a single shell. Rather, I have alias crun="conda run --live-stream -n" and use that to run software from different environments.

i was expecting conda activate to do what your proposed conda switch would do. To me the current behavior is a bit odd because activate is somehow deactivating the previous env, but still it remembers it when i deactivate. Am I saying something completely stupid (I m rather new to conda)?

Certainly not a stupid question, it just is what it is. I did not find it surprising behavior, but I also don’t think there is anything particularly right or wrong here in implementation. More an issue of documentation of behavior as you clearly stated. I think the expected behavior you described could be useful, hence the suggestion to turn it into a feature request. But also wanted to indicate that as somewhat of a power-user, I have the opinion that conda activate is overused, and conda run is often better for certain tasks, especially ones that involve activating multiple envs.

yeah btw thx a lot about conda run - i was not really aware of it and i started using it - it is indeed true that oftentimes i do activate whereas it would be better/easier to to run

It is in the documentation:

By default, conda activate will deactivate the current environment before activating the new environment and reactivate it when deactivating the new environment.

So it is expected

ok fair enough. from conda activate -h or conda deactivate -h this behavior is not very clear but the page you referred to leaves no doubts
